# Postgres Order different between Development and Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

In the Rails controller:

```
Item.all.order(:reading)
```

Order output in Development:
け,
けけ,
けけけ,
す,
すす,
すすす

Order output in Production (Heroku):
け,
す,
けけ,
すす,
けけけ,
すすす

It appears first sorted by length, then properly 'alphabetically'.
Repo: https://github.com/BuSensei/busensei

Comment: can you please post the sql query

Comment: maybe the `reading`  attribute is different in both `db`

Comment: Are the versions same?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting for how to sort characters called `LC_COLLATE`. Heroku uses a non-UTF8 setting by default on the database, which may not be altered. However, postgres supports setting `LC_COLLATE` on the table itself, or the column even.